# Can't find httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, opensuse

I can't find httpd.conf

I am running openSuse 11, and installed apache, its started and working.

Answer (score 5):

Try using

> updatedb
>   locate httpd.conf

Answer (score 3):

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Alternatively you could use the find command:
find /etc -name httpd.conf

Answer (score 2):

If you installed the package, you can use RPM to find which files belong to the package.

```
rpm -ql apache2
```

and replace apache2 with the package name you installed.  You can use

```
rpm -qa
```

to list all packages

Answer (score 1):

I think Suse uses apache2 now, so it wouldn't be httpd.conf, it would be

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

Just installed the apache2 package on my 11.0 workstation. The httpd.conf file showed up at:

```
 /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also be able to find the path to this file in the init script.  Usually config files are passed as arguments or at least mentioned in most init scripts.  So, something like this may work.

#grep httpd.conf /etc/init.d/apache2

Answer (score 0):

whereis httpd

look in each of the folders listed